# OpenLayers 3 - ZoomSlider outside the map

Tags: openlayers

I am building a map with OpenLayers and I want to display a custom ZoomSlider outside of the map.

I know that displaying controls outside of the map goes like this:

JavaScript:

```
var ctrl= new ol.control.Zoom({
        target: document.getElementById('ctrl')
    });
map.addControl(ctrl);
```

Html:

```
    <div id="ctrl"></div>
```

But it doesn't work with the ZoomSlider Control...

Any ideas?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/07zngj0j/) is a Fiddle which shows the problem

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `target` is not an option for zoom slider according to the [api doc](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.control.ZoomSlider.html). Use `setTarget()` method as shown below.

```
var ctrlSlider= new ol.control.ZoomSlider();
ctrlSlider.setTarget(document.getElementById('zoomSlider'));
map.addControl(ctrlSlider);
```

Updated your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/07zngj0j/5/).

Answer (score 0):

I achieve something by playing with the `.ol-` classes (display at the right of the map):

```
#map{ 
  width: 80%;
  position: absolute;
 }

.ol-zoomslider {
  position:fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: auto;
  right: 20px;
}

.ol-slider-thumb{
  left:0px;
}
```

I don't know why this is not working with `target`.

Comment: Thanks! css can help fixing the problem but unfortunately this is not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: relative style makes the position out of the map. just give absolute position with left, top on #zoom, #zoomslider. it has target property so touching `ol-` is meaningless